# Replace all occurrences of a character between two strings

Tags: regex, string, replace, find, notepad++

I want to replace all space occurrences between `string1` and `string2` with a `_` character on all lines of a text document using Notepad++.

Examples:

```
string1 this is a first example string2
string1 this is a second example string2
```

Expected result:

```
string1_this_is_a_first_example_string2
string1_this_is_a_second_example_string2
```

I tried this expression `(?<=string1)(\s*)(?=string2)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Bilel, please provide your expected output for a `string1 this is a string1 first example string2` string.

Comment: yaeh and expected output for a `string1 this is a string2 first example string2` string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**: `(?:\G(?!^)|string1)(?:(?!string1|string2).)*?\K\h(?=.*string2)`
**Replace With**: `_`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQtAlV/1).

**NOTE**:

- If you need to only match regular spaces, replace `\h` with a regular space
- A more appropriate check for the end of the previous successful match is `\G(?!^(?<![\s\S]))`, but if your expected matches are on a single line, you might go on using `\G(?!^)`.

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|string1)` - either the end of the previous match (but not start of a line) or `string1`
- `(?:(?!string1|string2).)*?`  - any char, 0 or more times, but as few as possible, that is not starting `string1` or `string2` char sequence
- `\K` - discard the text matched so far
- `\h` - any horizontal whitespace
- `(?=.*string2)` - there must be a `string2` after any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible immediately to the right of the current location.

[image]

Comment: doesnat work, the erroneus matching can be seen here https://regex101.com/r/AoWJkw/1regex

Comment: @Edward It is correct and work as expected, because there is no requirement to only match spaces between the closest `string1` and `string2`. Had there been such a requirement, I would have posted `(?:\G(?!^)|string1)(?:(?!string1|string2).)*?\K\h(?=(?:(?!string1).)*?string2)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SSQwPu/1).

Comment: No. If the original intent was to blow past `string1`s to find the next string2 you wouldn't have put `(?:(?!string1|string2).)*?` in the regex when `(?:(?!string2).)*?` is all thats needed.

Comment: In the regex case mentioned in yuor commnt and the the posted regex case, the closure end check is not actualy done at the end after each match as it exponentially is too time cerneuming. The way its done nowdayz is at the beginning, once, where first _`string1`_ is matched.